# How to back-transform log data from t-tests

Tags: r, t-test, paired-data

The question may seem simple but the more I read up on this the more difficult it gets. I transformed my data (log) and ran a paired t-test. When I backtransformed the mean difference from this I ended up with a value that didn't make sense.
I'm working with population changes in states in ten years (2000 and 2010). Back-transforming the mean difference resulted in a one person difference between the two sets of data. I've read that log-transforming for a t-test just doesn't make sense when there are non parametric approaches (wilcoxon test).

I also read from these forums that t-tests on log-transformed data actually processes geometric means opposed to arithmetic means and therefore the mean differences calculated from transformed data might not be dependable when back-transforming. 
I've ran the non-parametric option from the MASS package

```
wilcox.test(x,y, paired=T)
```

It shows the significant difference but doesn't show a mean difference (I think it's because the test is based on a rank-system?).

Am I by chance missing something here?

One more thing to add, I was made aware from some other posts that the t.test() in R already assumes unequal variances. I am wondering that if it accounts for one parametric assumption, could I effectively use it despite violating normality assumptions?

Comment: Perhaps clarify: (1) What *exactly* you did and (2) why you think it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Log transforming doesn't make sense when using a non-parametric test because a log transformation typically doesn't change the rank of the score, i.e. `rank(x) == rank(log(x))`. So because a test like the Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test uses rank scores the test statistic doesn't change when log-transforming (it's also the reason why it doesn't show a mean difference). Maybe start with describing what problem you have with your data (with figures/`summary`) that requires log-transformation and post the results of your tests on transformed and non-transformed data to help us understand the problem.